# Fixing table headers for scrolling TableLayout with dynamically added content

Tags: android

I currently have a table in an android application that I am developing for a class to which content is added dynamically from the code. The set of data that is added to the table will be rather large, so the table must be able to scroll. I needed to have a fixed header that remains as the rest of the content scrolls. In order to do this, I put the header in a completely separate `TableLayout`, with an additional invisible row to keep the formatting neat, as per the method described on [this blog](http://sdroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/fixed-header-in-tablelayout.html).

However, I find that, despite making the row invisible, a vertical space where the row would go is present. In the example given in the blog, the height of each `TextView` within the dummy (invisible) row is set to `"0dp"`. However, trying to set the height of the table by getting the `LayoutParams` and setting the `height` property to `0` seems to create more problems. It makes a larger space, meanwhile making the actual header content completely invisible.

Unfortunately, I am restricted from using outside libraries by my teacher, so I really need a solution to this problem instead of an alternative such as TableFixHeaders.

Comment: Are you limited to using only `tableLayouts`?

Comment: No, I am not. Is something better that might provide the functionality I need?

Comment: Well, I don't know the full context of your scenario, however I would have my parent layout `LinearLayout (vertical)` then within, the child layouts would be `LinearLayout (horizontal)` - this would be your header. The other child would be a `listView`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment above, I would have something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerarLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/myText"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linerarLayout1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I changed the parent to `RelativeLayout`